# How to Run a Stored Procedure using the Table Values as Parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure intended to insert data into a table and it has 6 parameters

SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tb_mis_am_node]
@pid_code varchar(10),
@id_code varchar(10),
@description varchar(50),
@disp_order int, /*** This will serve as a display order sequence ***/
@username varchar(20),
@user_key int,
```

Now i want to run this SP and populate its parameters using the values in my existing table with the same number and name of column

Table:

```
SELECT  [pid_code]
      ,[id_code]
      ,[description]
      ,[disp_order]
      ,[username]
      ,[user_key]
  FROM [webloan_helper].[dbo].[tbl_ledger_add]
```

How will I execute it?

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Which DBMS do you use? Please add the corect tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If re-writing your stored procedure<sup>1,2</sup> is not on the cards, and nor is incorporating the body into your current method<sup>2</sup>, then your only real choice remaining is to loop.

To loop, you use a [cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180169.aspx) and a `WHILE`, something like:

```
DECLARE @pid_code varchar(10)
DECLARE @id_code varchar(10)
DECLARE @description varchar(50)
DECLARE @disp_order int
DECLARE @username varchar(20)
DECLARE @user_key int

DECLARE boris cursor local fast_forward FOR SELECT  [pid_code]
      ,[id_code]
      ,[description]
      ,[disp_order]
      ,[username]
      ,[user_key]
  FROM [webloan_helper].[dbo].[tbl_ledger_add]

OPEN boris
FETCH NEXT FROM boris INTO @pid_code,@id_code,@description,
                           @disp_order,@username,@user_key

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC [sp_tb_mis_am_node] @pid_code,@id_code,@description,
                           @disp_order,@username,@user_key

    FETCH NEXT FROM boris INTO @pid_code,@id_code,@description,
                           @disp_order,@username,@user_key
END
CLOSE boris
DEALLOCATE boris
```

---

<sup>1</sup>There is one bit of re-writing of the current procedure that I would [recommend, however](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name.

---

<sup>2</sup>With the intention, in either case, that you re-write them to be set-based rather than working with a single row. For the re-write of the stored procedure instance, this would mean taking a [table-valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(SQL.100).aspx).

Comment: @RyanAbarquez - no problem - if you want to participate more in SO, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: is there any for the query to execute faster? Just askin :)

Comment: @RyanAbarquez - as alluded to in a couple of places in the answer, it would be far better to re-write the existing stored procedure (either to replace itself or just inserted into this current piece of code) so that it performs a *set* based operation (taking the entire table as input and inserting *multiple* rows in the destination, as a single query). But how viable that is, I can't say since all we currently know is the name (and parameters) of the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Create Procedure ExecuteProc
AS
Begin
    Declare @RowNumber INT;  -- Row number of Table webloan_helper
    SET @RowNumber = 1;

```
While (@RowNumber <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM webloan_helper))
Begin
    Declare @pid_code varchar(10);
    Declare @id_code varchar(10);
    Declare @description varchar(50);
    Declare @disp_order int;
    Declare @username varchar(20);
    Declare @user_key int;

    Set @pid_code = (Select pid_code From (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By pid_code) As RowNum, * From webloan_helper) t2 Where RowNum = @RowNumber);
    Set @id_code = (Select id_code From (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By pid_code) As RowNum, * From webloan_helper) t2 Where RowNum = @RowNumber);
    Set @description = (Select [description] From (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By pid_code) As RowNum, * From webloan_helper) t2 Where RowNum = @RowNumber);
    Set @disp_order = (Select disp_order From (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By pid_code) As RowNum, * From webloan_helper) t2 Where RowNum = @RowNumber);
    Set @username = (Select username From (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By pid_code) As RowNum, * From webloan_helper) t2 Where RowNum = @RowNumber);
    Set @user_key = (Select user_key From (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By pid_code) As RowNum, * From webloan_helper) t2 Where RowNum = @RowNumber);

    Exec sp_tb_mis_am_node @pid_code,@id_code,@description,@disp_order,@username,@user_key;
     -- Order By Should be unique column
```

SET @RowNumber= @RowNumber+ 1;
    End

End

Comment: That looks like a horrible way of attempting to avoid the word "cursor" appearing in your code. How many separate queries of the table do you perform here?